# How do you find the rolling maximum of a value that starts over at the end of each month? Pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

This is what I want to work:

```
rtl['to date monthly max'] = rtl['actual_system_demand'].rolling('M').max()
```

But I get the error:

> ValueError:  is a non-fixed frequency

I don't want to use '30D' because I need the value to reset at the beginning of the next month. I use pd.Grouper() for a lot of calculations but I don't know how to make that work here.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the time to read this post on how to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as how to provide a [minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest what column `actual_system_demand` has datetime format.
If is true, you can extract month and year for groupby, then apply rolling max entire each month:

```
rtl['year'] = rtl['actual_system_demand'].dt.year
rtl['month'] = rtl['actual_system_demand'].dt.month
rtl.groupby(['year', 'month'])['actual_system_demand'].rolling().max().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Also, Instead of `rolling()` and `max()` you aslo can use function `cummax()`:

```
rtl.groupby(['year', 'month'])['actual_system_demand'].cummax().reset_index(drop=True)
```